# multiple SLF4J bindings intellij linux

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, gradle

I am trying to run a war generated by gradle from IntelliJ idea.

When I run the war through idea's tomcat run configuration, I get the SLF4J multiple bindings warning as following:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/slf4j-jcl-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/slf4j-nop-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/virtue/prog/idea_project/out/artifacts/websitebase-app/exploded/websitebase-app-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

The SLF4J inside websitebase-app-1.0.0.war is the one from my application. The SLF4J bindings from /usr/share/java are additional SLF4J bindings I do not want. I do not know how to remove them since when I run the application from gradle I do not have those included at runtime.

How can I configure my application or IntelliJ idea, not to have those extra SLF4J bindings included?

I am trying to start the application within IntelliJ. I created a run configuration inside IntelliJ that uses my locally installed tomcat7. I installed tomcat from the repository, I am running NetRunner 16 which is a  distribution of Kubuntu.

Output of `jps -v` when the tomcat instance is running:

```
5281 Jps -Dapplication.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle -Xms8m
4808 RemoteMavenServer -Djava.awt.headless=true -Didea.version==14.1.5 -Xmx512m -Didea.maven.embedder.version=3.0.5 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
5164 Launcher -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs="" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dpreload.project.path=/home/virtue/prog/idea_project -Dpreload.config.path=/home/virtue/.IntelliJIdea14/config/options -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=7407435799211631797 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djps.file.types.component.name=FileTypeManager -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=CA -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea14 -Didea.home.path=/home/virtue/devtools/idea/idea-IU-141.2735.5 -Didea.config.path=/home/virtue/.IntelliJIdea14/config -Didea.plugins.path=/home/virtue/.IntelliJIdea14/config/plugins -Djps.log.dir=/home/virtue/.IntelliJIdea14/system/log/build-log -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/virtue/.IntelliJIdea14/system/compile-server/_temp_
4669 Main -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/virtue/devtools/idea/idea-IU-141.2735.5/bin/../lib/boot.jar -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/home/virtue/devtools/idea/idea-IU-141.2735.5/bin/idea64.vmoptions -XX:ErrorFile=/home/virtue/java_error_in_IDEA_%p.log -Djb.restart.code=88 -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea14
4958 GradleDaemon -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=CA -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant
5167 Bootstrap -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/virtue/.IntelliJIdea14/system/tomcat/Unnamed_marble-gradle-common_3/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:48465,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:/home/virtue/devtools/idea/idea-IU-141.2735.5/plugins/Groovy/lib/agent/gragent.jar -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/home/virtue/.IntelliJIdea14/system/tomcat/Unnamed_marble-gradle-common_3 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/virtue/.IntelliJIdea14/system/tomcat/Unnamed_marble-gradle-common_3/temp
```

Comment: Where does the tomcat come from? Is it a distribution package?

Comment: tomcat7 7.0.56-2ubuntu0.1 I am running Netrunner 16 which is a distribution of Kubuntu.

Comment: Somehow the path "/usr/share/java/*" appeared on your classpath, not sure if intellij did that or you have changed the tomcat settings. Could you provide output of `jps -v` for that running tomcat?

Comment: You need to run the command when tomcat is running.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of solutions here :

- Make sure that you include only one slf4j dependency in your class path.
- If your project has dependency on other project and the other one use slf4j as well with different version try to use **excusion**

```js
<exclusions>
   <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```